# angular cli version mapping to angular versions?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I just executed a cmd of "ng -v" to get the version of the Angular CLI installed on my computer. The output of this command is "1.7.0." Is there a webpage with a mapping of Angular CLI version to Angular version?  For example, does a CLI version of 1.7.0 map to a particular Angular version like 5.0 by default?  Or is there some level of independence between CLI version and Angular version? For example, will a particular version of the CLI support a particular range of Angular versions?  Is there a CLI command that I can execute to get this information or is this information published anywhere online?

Answer (score 0):

This is only a partial answer! I needed to maintain a Angular 4 (4.4.7) application. The version of the CLI I needed to use was 1.1.3. I found it extremely difficult to get that information, so maybe the next guy coming along can find it here.

Answer (score -1):

This has changed on the newest version of the CLI and the newest version of angular, Angular 6. Now, the version of the CLI and Angular will be the same. All the CLIs work with old + current version, but angular CLI 6 only supports version 5 and 6

Comment: "`All the CLIs work with old + current version`" - No. This statement is not true. Angular/cli v6 is completely different than the earlier versions of the CLI. Have you even tried angular/cli v6 against an Angular v2,4,5 project?

Comment: Partially true. Angular CLI 6 supports version 5

Comment: A "partially true" answer is not a correct answer. How about angular cli v1.x.x - is that compatible with a v6 project?

Comment: Voted down as it does not answer the question.